# What is Ms. Saotome referring to in her rant about the end of the world?

Tags: madoka-magica

During Ms. Saotome's rather-unhinged rant about the end of the world towards the beginning of the **Rebellion** movie, she says the following:

> とある宗教の祭礼の日にあわせて、日食と月食が６回起こっちゃうという話です！
>
> I'm talking about how on the festival days of a certain religion, six solar and lunar eclipses will occur!

Is this a reference to a real-world practice, or is this some sort of weird Madoka-universe eschatological thing?

Answer (score 5):

After quite a lot of digging, I think I've figured out what's going on here.

Apparently, over the course of 2014 and 2015, there will be a series of four lunar eclipses ("blood moons") and two solar eclipses that occur on Jewish holy days.<sup>1</sup> While the supposed eschatological consequences of this are not entirely clear to me, they are apparently dire. As reported in [The Jewish Press](http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/messianic-blood-moon-rising-on-passover-seder/2013/10/06/):

> There will be a string of four "blood moons" in the year 5775 [i.e. 2014-15 CE], and one of them will shine over the Passover seder. Whenever this happened in the past, enormous events took place in Jewish history.

---

## Notes

<sup>1</sup> For more information, see: [Red Moon Rapture](http://www.redmoonrapture.com/2014-2015.html); [FreeRepublic](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-religion/2010282/posts); [The Jewish Press](http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/messianic-blood-moon-rising-on-passover-seder/2013/10/06/).

Comment: You should consider accepting your own answer, I think it's sound.